# What are the reasons for having different loop types?

Tags: loops

Between for, while & do-while loops, it has already been established that they are functionally equivalent and the choice of loop is more of a matter of style.

That said, is there any rationale to the origins of these three different loop formats? For each of them, are there any particular situations or contexts where it would be preferable or more appropriate than the others, such as for readability purposes etc?

Comment: They aren't functionally equivalent. Each of them have different strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: For the most part you use a `for` loop when you know how many times to iterate. and a `while` loop when you don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`for`:**

- Used for "stupid" tasks like iterating through an array
- Used when you know how many iterations you will make

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { magic }

for (String s : arr) { magic }
```

**`while`:**

- Used with sophisticated stop condition
- Used for infinite loops

```
while (true) { magic }

while (x % 2 != 0) { magic; x = randomInt(); }

Node cur = head;
while (cur != null) { magic; cur = cur.next; }
```

I'm not sure what languages you're familiar with, so I will make a guess and pick Java.
Let me know if I'm totally wrong.

Comment: This is actually for C++, but I left it out of the tags because these three loop types are pretty generic. The reason why I say they're functionally equivalent is that there's no behaviour you can achieve on one loop type that you can't on another. For example, if I declare an integer counter, a while loop can essentially work identically to a for loop. An additional if statement can turn a do-while into a while. That's what I meant by equivalent, and I learnt that from other answers here in the past.

Comment: Basically, there are no circumstances where a program using one loop type can't be rewritten to use a different loop type. So, with that in mind, is there any concrete reason why three different loop types exist, or is there any design intent for each type?

Comment: You're correct - they are functionally equivalent. You can think of for loops as being syntactic sugar for while loops (or vice versa, whichever).

The point is that sometimes it's much cleaner to use a for loop (look at examples). Only one line vs 3 in while loop (initialize counter, stop condition, increment). On the other hand, sometimes while loops suit your needs better. Putting a complicated stop condition in the for loop can be ugly, and so you would use a while loop in that case. It's basically just for readability.

Comment: If you have a while loop and need to put statements before it that are also in the body, to remove redundancy, you use a do-while. Look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_while_loop#C.2B.2B).

Comment: @thegreatjedi in a TL;DR fashion, a do while loop is for code that should execute *at least once*. A while loop might never execute, if the condition is false at the start. However, a do-while will always execute at least once, since the condition is checked at the end of the loop block.